# Comment appelle-t-on la prise/technique permettant de maîtriser un individu agressif grâce à un escalier?

Tags: choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation, reformulation, lexique

Quel est le nom de la prise qui permet à quiconque, à des agents de sécurité, à des agents de la paix, à des policiers ou à toute personne dépositaire de l’autorité, de prendre le dessus sur une personne **agressive** , souvent sous l’emprise de l’alcool, d’autres fois sous l’influence de stupéfiants, en la faisant tomber en douceur à plat ventre sur un escalier? Technique qui est d’autant plus efficace qu’une personne est très **alcoolisée** au point d’être molle et malléable. La prise ou la technique d’immobilisation permet de gérer, ou mieux de maîtriser, une personne agressive délicatement de manière à éviter de lui infliger toute forme de blessures.

Comment: ***?*** ***?*** ***?***

Comment: C’est une prise qui permet de maîtriser un individu en douceur, sans le blesser. On m’a déjà parlé de cette technique en la désignant avec un nom…Peut-être était-ce un nom inventé par celui qui m’en avait parlé.

Comment: Pour pouvoir répondre il faudrait un peu plus de contexte à mon avis. Qui pratique ces techniques? Des sportifs? Quel sport? Des personnes dépositaires de l'autorité publique?

Comment: Dans le contexte, il est question de gérer une personne agressive et sous l’influence de l’alcool. Qui pratique ces techniques? Un agent de sécurité, un agent de la paix, un policier, une personne souhaitant se défendre…

Comment: On est sur du très spécifique là. Jamais entendu parlé de cette technique d'immobilisation/interpellation par les forces de l'ordre. A première ça semble un peu dangereux, mais je n'y connais rien.

Comment: Une personne peut très bien être agressive verbalement sans pour autant l’être physiquement…

Comment: C'est bien vrai !

Comment: Et il ne faut pas toujours prendre les termes au pied de la lettre, ici il ne s’agit pas de faire chuter quelqu’un brutalement, mais plutôt de l’amener à déposer ses genoux contre une marche d’escalier pour ensuite le faire allonger, de gré ou de force, à plat ventre sur un palier.

Comment: J’admets que ma question manquait de précision, il n’est pas question ici d’un grand escalier comptant plus de 50 marches! C’est un palier avec quatre marches que l’on retrouve parfois à l’entrée d’un bar, immédiatement après la porte, d’une boîte de nuit, d’un cabaret ou d’un bistrot.

Comment: Pour éclairer le tout, il y a la porte d’entrée, suivie d’un palier (prisme rectangulaire surélevé par rapport au sol) et de quatre marches sinon cinq, souvent équipé d’une rampe, qu’il faut descendre pour arriver au niveau du plancher du bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le lutteur que j'étais dirait "un amené au sol", s'il s'agit d'accompagner un ivrogne peu rétif. Et je parlerais plus volontiers d'un "plaquage" si l'opération exigeait une dose de percussion ? Pour tout vous dire, il est difficile de comprendre si vous parlez :

- d'un accompagnement/projection (emmener quelqu'un au sol en le déséquilibrant)
- d'une soumission (emmener quelqu'un au sol par la contrainte à la douleur)
- d'une immobilisation (maintenir quelqu'un au sol et neutralisé en lui faisant le moins mal possible)

À différents endroits de votre question, vous évoquez une technique spécifique de "faire tomber quelqu'un en douceur à plat ventre". Ce qui nous mettrait dans le premier cas de figure et n'a pas réellement de nom précis : c'est évidemment une projection ou un amené si l'adversaire n'a aucun tonus à opposer. À d'autres moments, vous parlez plutôt de le maîtriser au sol. Cette autre panoplie de techniques (immobilisations) est nettement distincte de la première. Dans les commentaires, enfin, vous nous proposez "mais plutôt de l’amener à déposer ses genoux contre une marche d’escalier pour ensuite le faire allonger, de gré ou de force, à plat ventre sur un palier", ce qui m'évoque plutôt des techniques de soumission par la douleur en position debout (typiquement, une clef), donc une troisième catégorie de techniques.

Je dois par ailleurs vous avouer que je crois difficilement en la possibilité matérielle de :

- "faire tomber quelqu'un d'alcoolisé ou drogué..." : donc imprévisible, très vulnérable, potentiellement agité, difficile à rattraper, et privé de réflexes efficaces pour se réceptionner. Sommes-nous d'accord sur cet axiome ?
- "... en douceur sur le ventre..." : je pense que si j'en étais réduit à faire tomber quelqu'un "EN DOUCEUR dans des escaliers", opération particulièrement dangereuse pour mon adversaire, la douceur commanderait précisément que je ne le fasse SURTOUT PAS tomber sur le ventre (c'est-à-dire le menton et le visage contre le rebord des marches et dans une pente), mais bien au contraire sur le cul, en déséquilibre arrière. L'être naturellement doux que je suis se dit qu'on (sur)vit mieux en se fêlant le coccyx qu'en se déboîtant la mâchoire, en perdant 5 dents et en tombant dans les vapes à cause du choc sous le menton alors qu'on est préalablement intoxiqué. Je n'hésite d'ailleurs pas à qualifier toute technique visant à projeter un ivrogne ou un drogué, tête la première et face contre les marches d'un escalier de potentiellement létale : c'est vous dire si je trouve ça doux.
- "... sur un escalier" : c'est-à-dire un endroit où le risque de le blesser gravement est démultiplié par rapport à un terrain plat, pour dire les choses comme elles sont ? L'endroit par excellence où les chutes tuent le plus (avec les baignoires et les piscines), statistiquement.

Comment: Si ma mémoire ne me trompe, il était question d’une clef! Je tiens à vous remercier pour cette réponse riche en détails et en vocabulaire! Wow!